# Сложность в работе запроса mysql

Tags: php, mysql, action

Обработчик принимает `textarea` и сохраняет её содержимое в базу данных.

Вот фрагмет формы:

```
<textarea name="massage" id="teamMember" cols="30" rows="10">
    Игрок 1:
    ФИО: ФИО
    Позывной: 
    ----
    Игрок 2:
    ФИО: ФИО
    Позывной: 
</textarea>
```

А обработчик этого кода вот (остальные данные тоже заполнены):

```
$teamMember = htmlspecialchars($_POST['teamMember']);
$q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tournament_team (`name`,`capitanName`, `capitanNick`, `capitanPhone`, `member`)
        VALUES ($teamName, $capitanName, $capitanNick,$capitanPhone, ,$teamMember)");
```

И после запроса MySQL выдает такую ошибку:

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax**; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Игрок 1: ФИО: Иванов Петр Васильевичadgasdgasdg По' at line 2

Не могу понять, в чем сложность данного фрагмента кода?

Comment: Если вы только начинаете работу с PHP, то сразу избавьтесь от привычки вклеивать пользовательские данные в запрос и научитесь работать с PDO.

Comment: _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных в текст запроса, используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных. 
 http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

У вас вклинилась лишняя запятая перед $teamMember. Попробуйте ее убрать и выполнить запрос еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tournament_team (name,capitanName,capitanNick,capitanPhone,member)
        VALUES (:teamName, :capitanName, :capitanNick,:capitanPhone, ,:teamMember)");
$q->bindParam(':teamName',$_POST['teamName']);
$q->bindParam(':capitanName',$_POST['capitanName']);
$q->bindParam(':capitanNick',$_POST['capitanNick']);
$q->bindParam(':capitanPhone',$_POST['capitanPhone']);
$q->bindParam(':teamMember',$_POST['teamMembar']);
$q->execute();
```